# How to send traces to jaeger via grpc

Tags: go, grpc, trace

I have started the jeager locally in docker:

```
services:
    jaeger:
      image: jaegertracing/all-in-one
      ports:
        - "14268:14268"
        - "16686:16686"
```

Then I connect to it via grpc. I am trying to connect through the port that the docker sends.

```
tctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 

5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    const maxCallMsgSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100

    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(
        tctx,
        "localhost:14268",
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(
            grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(maxCallMsgSize),
            grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(maxCallMsgSize),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("conn: %w", err)
    }

    exp, err := otlptracegrpc.New(tctx, otlptracegrpc.WithGRPCConn(conn))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("exporter: %w", err)
    }

    res, err := resource.Merge(
        resource.Default(),
        resource.NewWithAttributes(
            semconv.SchemaURL,
            semconv.ServiceName(serviceName),
        ),
    )

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("resource: %w", err)
    }

    tp := tracesdk.NewTracerProvider(
        tracesdk.WithSampler(tracesdk.AlwaysSample()),
        tracesdk.WithBatcher(exp),
        tracesdk.WithResource(res),
    )

    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext{}, propagation.Baggage{}))

    tracer = otel.Tracer("trader-bot")
```

But when you try to send a span to the jeager, the following error comes out:

```
export: context deadline exceeded: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"
```

What could be the problem here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

## Sending Traces to jaeger via grpc

You don't seem to be using the correct port for `grpc` as per the [documentation](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.55/getting-started/) which is `4317`

[image]

You can try the following example taken from documentation.

### [opentelemetry.io » jaeger reference](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/go/exporters/#jaeger)

- To try out the OTLP exporter, since v1.35.0 you can run Jaeger as an OTLP endpoint and for trace visualization in a Docker container:

```bash
docker run -d --name jaeger \
  -e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true \
  -p 16686:16686 \
  -p 4317:4317 \
  -p 4318:4318 \
  jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

### [opentelemetry.io » oltp](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/go/exporters/#otlp)

To learn more on how to use the OTLP HTTP exporter, try the [otel-collector example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/tree/main/example/otel-collector)

- Go code

```bash
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"

    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/attribute"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlptrace/otlptracegrpc"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/propagation"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/resource"
    sdktrace "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace"
    semconv "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv/v1.24.0"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace"
)

// Initializes an OTLP exporter, and configures the corresponding trace and
// metric providers.
func initProvider() (func(context.Context) error, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    res, err := resource.New(ctx,
        resource.WithAttributes(
            // the service name used to display traces in backends
            semconv.ServiceName("test-service"),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create resource: %w", err)
    }

    // If the OpenTelemetry Collector is running on a local cluster (minikube or
    // microk8s), it should be accessible through the NodePort service at the
    // `localhost:30080` endpoint. Otherwise, replace `localhost` with the
    // endpoint of your cluster. If you run the app inside k8s, then you can
    // probably connect directly to the service through dns.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "localhost:4317",
        // Note the use of insecure transport here. TLS is recommended in production.
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.WithBlock(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create gRPC connection to collector: %w", err)
    }

    // Set up a trace exporter
    traceExporter, err := otlptracegrpc.New(ctx, otlptracegrpc.WithGRPCConn(conn))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create trace exporter: %w", err)
    }

    // Register the trace exporter with a TracerProvider, using a batch
    // span processor to aggregate spans before export.
    bsp := sdktrace.NewBatchSpanProcessor(traceExporter)
    tracerProvider := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.AlwaysSample()),
        sdktrace.WithResource(res),
        sdktrace.WithSpanProcessor(bsp),
    )
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tracerProvider)

    // set global propagator to tracecontext (the default is no-op).
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext{})

    // Shutdown will flush any remaining spans and shut down the exporter.
    return tracerProvider.Shutdown, nil
}

func main() {
    log.Printf("Waiting for connection...")

    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt)
    defer cancel()

    shutdown, err := initProvider()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("failed to shutdown TracerProvider: %w", err)
        }
    }()

    tracer := otel.Tracer("test-tracer")

    // Attributes represent additional key-value descriptors that can be bound
    // to a metric observer or recorder.
    commonAttrs := []attribute.KeyValue{
        attribute.String("attrA", "chocolate"),
        attribute.String("attrB", "raspberry"),
        attribute.String("attrC", "vanilla"),
    }

    // work begins
    ctx, span := tracer.Start(
        ctx,
        "CollectorExporter-Example",
        trace.WithAttributes(commonAttrs...))
    defer span.End()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        _, iSpan := tracer.Start(ctx, fmt.Sprintf("Sample-%d", i))
        log.Printf("Doing really hard work (%d / 10)\n", i+1)

        <-time.After(time.Second)
        iSpan.End()
    }

    log.Printf("Done!")
}
```

### How to run this?

```bash
$ go mod init tmp
...

$ go mod tidy
...

$ go run .
2024/03/11 13:34:43 Waiting for connection...
2024/03/11 13:34:43 Doing really hard work (1 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:44 Doing really hard work (2 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:45 Doing really hard work (3 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:46 Doing really hard work (4 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:47 Doing really hard work (5 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:48 Doing really hard work (6 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:49 Doing really hard work (7 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:50 Doing really hard work (8 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:51 Doing really hard work (9 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:52 Doing really hard work (10 / 10)
2024/03/11 13:34:53 Done!
```

### Check the ports of running docker container of jaeger

```bash
docker ps
```

### Access the jaeger dashboard http://localhost:16686

[image]